# iOS best way to change the UI when orientation is changed

Tags: ios, user-interface, orientation

Which is the best way to change the UI when orientation is changed?

For example, use two different UIView one portrait and a landscape and show one of both if orientation is changed, or use one UIView and change the UI control sizes and positions?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Change to custom UI for landscape");
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Change to custom UI for portrait");

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that ```willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation``` is now deprecated (cf. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621458-willanimaterotationtointerfaceor)).

Answer (score 2):

I always recommend using the autoresizingmask for all the subviews in the view controller view. With this being set correctly all the views will resize automatically from the orientation and you **don't** need the extra rotation specific subviews (one portrait view and one landscape view).

Comment: Hello
some cases does not give the expected effect of autoresizingmask, for example there is 9x9 UI buttons on portrait view, how can I do it with the suggested method? If I change the view to landscape need to move some buttons horizontally, because out of the visible area.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you want to keep the margin from the edge of the view to the button? If that is the case then you can achieve that with the autoresizingmask.

Comment: Okay, how can I do this with calculator buttons for example?