# iOS - Launch view controller depending on orientation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, screen-orientation

I am using Xcode 5. Once the app enters AppDelegate.m, I would like to detect the orientation of the device and depending on whether the device is in portrait/landscape mode, display the appropriate view controller.

This is the code I have:

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
    SplashScreenViewController *splashScreen = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:FILENAME_WITH_IDIOM(@"SplashScreenViewController") bundle:nil];
    [self.mainWindowViewController presentViewController:splashScreen animated:NO completion:nil];
}
else if (([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | ([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    SplashViewControllerLandscape *splashLandscape = [[SplashViewControllerLandscape alloc] initWithNibName:FILENAME_WITH_IDIOM(@"SplashViewControllerLandscape") bundle:nil];
    [self.mainWindowViewController presentViewController:splashLandscape animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

This just shows me a blank screen. The cause of the problem is `[[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]` This method returns `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` unless device orientation notifications are switched on.

How do I fix this problem ?

Comment: Can you print [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] and see what is its value?

Comment: Also, what if you just show one of the splash screens without any checks, does that work? Even if it's not the right view controller for the current orientation?

Comment: Side note - Do not use the `UIInterfaceOrientation...` constants with `UIDevice orientation`. There are different device orientation constants.

Comment: And use `||`, not `|`. There's a huge difference.

Comment: The cause of the problem is `UIDeviceOrientation orientation;`It will return UIDeviceOrientationUnknown unless device orientation notifications are turned on

Comment: Your approach is prone to fail in many situations. Consider using a far more standard approach - that is, using orientation change callbacks - one example would be using [willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9553586/91282). And make sure you understand the purpose of a ViewController vs. the purpose of a View.